# Medir distância entre pontos de poligonos SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Criei um `SVG` bem simples com um triângulo.

```
<svg class="triangulo" height="210" width="500">
   <polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

E o que eu quero saber é como fazer um script que me resulte a distancia de dois pontos como neste exemplo:

[image]

Porém eu não precisa aparecer a linha e o número demarcando a distância, preciso apenas que retorne o valor do segmento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você já tenha as coordenadas em variáveis JavaScript, basta aplicar o Teorema de Pitágoras:

```
var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

Aplicando ao seu HTML, você pode fazer isto nos browsers que suportam o [SVG DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model#SVG_interfaces):

```
var triangulo = document.querySelector('.triangulo polygon');

// Os dois primeiros pontos do triângulo
var p1 = triangulo.points[0];
var p2 = triangulo.points[1];
// Distância entre esses dois pontos
var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2));
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/owu7w92n/</sup>